# Go template/html pass variable to nested template

Tags: html, templates, go

I am a bit confused by how Go templates execute my templates. I have a base layout and I would like to pass a string variable, so my base template can execute another template based on the string variable I passed.

This works fine.

```
{{ template "anotherTemplate" . }}
```

This does not work fine.

```
{{ $another := "anotherTemplate" }}
{{ template $another . }}
```

Comment: That's simply not allowed. If you want you can do `{{ if eq $another "anotherTemplate" }} {{ template "anotherTemplate" . }} {{ end }}`.. but not much more than that. The nested templates *need* to be known at parse time.

Comment: I see, i will try it out